# Update CSS color for all excluding within parent with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I've got a color picker which triggers the following jquery:

```
//event.color.toHex() = hex color code
$('#iframe-screen').contents().find('body a').css('color',event.color.toHex());
```

This will change the color of all links within #iframe-screen. However, I would like to exclude links that are within #menu. Ideally, without looping through all the links.

Is there a way to apply the CSS above to all links that aren't within #menu? Something like:

```
$('#iframe-screen').contents().find('body [not-parent]#menu a').css('color',event.color.toHex());
```

The #menu is a typical unordered list menu:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="">dont change</a></li>
<li><a href="">dont change</a></li>
<li><a href="">dont change</a></li>
</ul>
<a href=""> change</a>
<div><a href=""> change</a></div>
```

Comment: The loop exists, it's just that you don't see it.

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery .not() method like so:

```
$('#iframe-screen').contents().find('body a').not('#menu a').css('color',event.color.toHex());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) used here.

```
$('a').filter(function(){
 return $(this).closest('#menu').length == 0;
}).css('color',event.color.toHex());
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wD3MD/)

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way would be to wrap your content in `<div class="content"></div>` and keep your menu nav outside your wrapper then replace `.find('body a')` with `.find(.content a)`.

It would process faster than using a jquery solution.